# Delete in Gridview not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

If I use a hard coded value for the deletecommand (where JOB_ID = 123), it works, but when I try to use a parameter I get this error :

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00936: missing expression.

JOB_ID is a varchar2 field on the database. Any help would be great.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
 runat="server" DataKeyNames="JOB_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true">



    <columns>
              <asp:boundfield datafield="JOB_ID" headertext="Job ID"/>
              <asp:boundfield datafield="JOB_DATE_CLOSED" headertext="Posting Closes On"/>
              <asp:boundfield datafield="JOB_DESC" headertext="Job Description"/>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button id="DeleteButton" runat="server" text="Delete"
                CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this Record?');" >
                </asp:Button>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleInternet %>" 
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleInternet.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT JOB_ID, JOB_DATE_CLOSED, JOB_DESC FROM OWNER.JOB_POSTING" 

    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM OWNER.JOB_POSTING WHERE JOB_ID = @JOB_ID" >
    <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="JOB_ID" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The example here uses a different query syntax for parameters, it also uses `ControlParameter` instead of just `Parameter`.  I've never done such a thing personally, but maybe this will help you.  https://forums.oracle.com/thread/622971?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: maybe there is need for casting?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Garrison!

I changed @JOB_ID to :JOB_ID in the deletecommand, which was the syntax in the link you posted, and it worked. No idea why as almost all of the examples out there use @ for a parameter, but thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  Most of the examples you'll see online for .NET will be with SQL Server databases, since they're both MSFT products that "just work" together.